# How can I email a long list of emails in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have this database table that contains emails like 300 records,

```
emails{email,name,join_date);
```

and I want to email all of them something, how could I do this with php and mysql? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myEmailMessage = "";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails");
while($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    mail($info['email'], 'My Email Title', $myEmailMessage);
}
```

Now you just need to set $myEmailMessage to whatever you want to send to your users.

If you need more advanced emails (html, attachments, etc), you can take a look [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/getting-started-with-html-emails/)

Comment: You might also want to put a sleep or timer on there so it doesnt try to send them all at once, as your server's isp might see it as spamming, also it might hog resources sending that many at once.

Comment: im only going to send like 30 for now, do you think thats kool